# Java Application return super class when initialized

Tags: java

Nowadays we are on writing some core application that is all other application will be relying on. Without further due let me explain the logic with some codes,

We used to have a single java file that was 1000+ lines long and each application was having it as class inside, so when there was a change, each application had to edit the java file inside of it or simply fix one and copy to all. This is hard to implement as much as it is hard to maintain. Then we end-up with creating this as a separate application that is divided to smaller part, which is easy to maintain and also a core maybe a dependency to other application so we fix in one place and all other code applications are fixed too.

I've been thinking for a some great structure for this for a while want to use a builder patter for this as below

```
TheCore theCore = new TheCore().Builder()
.setSomething("params")
.setSomethingElse(true)
.build();
```

The problem arises now. Like so, I initialized the object but now I'm having access to that objects `public` class only. This application actually will have many small classes that has `public` functions that I don't want them to be static methods that can be called everytime. Instead I want those methods to be called only if `TheCore` class is initilized like;

```
// doSomething() will be from another class
theCore.doSomething()
```

There are some ideas I produced like

```
someOtherClass.doSomething(theCore)
```

which is injecting the main object as a parameter but still `someOtherClass` needs to be initialized or even a static method which doesn't make me feel comfortable and right way to that.

Actually I do not care if initializing `TheCore` would bring me a super object that includes all other classes inside initialized and ready to be accessed after I initialized `TheCore`. All I want in this structure to have a maintainable separate app and methods avaiable if only the main object which is `TheCore` is this circumstances is initialized.

What is to right way to achive it? I see that Java does not allow extending multiple classes even it if does, I'm not sure it that is right way...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by apps? Do you have separate java applications running independently which have to have some common functions, and that's why they have to include some package TheCore that provides that functions?

Comment: @SergeiTonoian Yes we have now 5-6 Applications and will be growing. Now all of them is having a long java class with too many functions inside and hard to maintain. Because when there is a change 5-6 applications should implement the same change manually. Now we are extracting that long java class outside as a core library so every application can benefit. I ended up with some implementations and we already started but still evaluating the idea.

Comment: It's definitely worth to extract that part of the code as library. Why do you want to init main class of the library first and only after that use other classes? Is core class supposed to prepare something so other parts can work?

Comment: @SergeiTonoian Yeah the Main part will initialize some special object that whole other part of the library will be useless if that object is not exist. So that will be a kind of checking mechanism (if its not initialized then nothing will be accessible) and also feels more convenient. Suppose that you don't have the connection to the DB but you are calling the method that writes into DB. Ofc it will have its own check mechanism that gonna say you - no connection - but not being able to call it if theres no connection is more making sense. (connection to DB is just example not what I intent)

Comment: it would be hard to implement. I mean you can not tell Java - hide public interfaces if something is not initialised. One way could be is to have all public methods in the main class, but you would end up with over-bloated interface, which is also very bad. One way is to keep API open, but those classes that need some resources to be prepared would throw exception saying some like - please init the main class first. Or you can inject some object that other classes need into them, so library user won't be able to init other classes without that object.

Comment: @SergeiTonoian I ended up with a design and I think that working now. I'll post it as an answer because its will be a long one as question is. Also you can share me your thoughts about it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After spending significant amount of time of thought I ended up that

```
// doSomething() will be from another class
theCore.doSomething()
```

is not suitable since many java classes could possibly have identical method names. So...

```
// doSomething() will be from another class
theCore.someOtherClass.doSomething()
```

would be a better approach.

To make it easier to understand I'll have to follow a complex path to explain it which is starting from the package classes first.

Think that I have a package named `Tools` and a class inside `SomeFancyTool`

```
main
└─java
  └─com
    └─<domainName>
      ├─Tools
      | └─SomeFancyTool.java
      └─TheCore.java
```

Now this `SomeFancyTool.java` must have a default access level which is actually package level access, because I don't want this classes to be accessed directly;

**SomeFancyTool.java**

```
package com.<domainName>.Tools

class SomeFancyTool{
   
   public String someStringMethod(){
      return "Some string!";
   }

   public int someIntMethod(){
      return 123;
   }

   public boolean someBooleanMethod(){
      return true;
   }

}
```

So now we have the `SomeFancyTool.java` class but `TheCore.java` cannot access it since it is accesible through its `Tools` package only. At this point I think of an Initializer class that is gonna be in the same package, initialize these private classes and return them with a function when called. So initiliazer class would look like this;

**ToolsInitializer.java**

```
package com.<domainName>.Tools

public class ToolsInitializer{
   private SomeFancyTool someFancyTool = new SomeFancyTool();
   
   public SomeFancyTool getSomeFancyTool(){
      return someFancyTool;
   }

}
```

Since `ToolsInitializer.java` can initialize all functional private classes inside in `Tools` package and also can return them as objects to outside of the package scope, still we are not able to use these methods as we cannot `import com.<domainName>.SomeFancyTool` from `TheCore.java` because it is package wide accessible. I think here we can benefit from implementation of the java `interface`. A class that is not functional alone, so no problem even if it is accessed since it's methods will be nothing but declarations.

At this point I'll rename `SomeFancyTool.java` to `SomeFancyToolImplementation.java` which it will be implementing the `interface` and call `SomeFancyTool.java` to the interface itself.

**SomeFancyTool.java** (now as an interface)

```
package com.<domainName>.Tools

public interface SomeFancyTool{

   public String someStringMethod();

   public int someIntMethod();

   public boolean someBooleanMethod();

}
```

and lets rename prior `SomeFancyTool.java` and implement the `interface`

**SomeFancyToolImplementation.java** (renamed)

```
package com.<domainName>.Tools

class SomeFancyToolImplementation implements SomeFancyTool{

   @override
   public String someStringMethod(){
      return "Some string!";
   }

   @override
   public int someIntMethod(){
      return 123;
   }

   @override
   public boolean someBooleanMethod(){
      return true;
   }

}
```

Now our structure has become like this with the final edits;

```
main
└─java
  └─com
    └─<domainName>
      ├─Tools
      | ├─SomeFancyTool.java
      | ├─SomeFancyToolImplementation.java
      | └─ToolsInitializer.java
      └─TheCore.java
```

Finally we can use our `TheCore.java` class to call all initializer classes with their methods to receive all these private classes inside as an object. This will allow external apps to call and initialize `TheCore` first to be able to access other methods.

**TheCore.java**

```
public class TheCore{
   private SomeFancyToolImplementation someFancyTool;

   public static class Builder{
      private SomeFancyToolImplementation someFancyTool;

      public Builder(){
         ToolsInitializer toolsInitializer = new ToolsInitializer();
         someFancyTool = toolsInitializer.getSomeFancyTool();
      }
  
      public Builder setSomeValues(){
         //some values that is needed.
         return this;
      }

      public Builder setSomeMoreValues(){
         //some values that is needed.
         return this;
      }

      public TheCore build(){
         TheCore theCore = new TheCore();
         theCore.someFancyTool = someFancyTool;
         return theCore;
      }

   }

}
```

**All Done and it is ready to use. Now the functional package classes and its methods that it relying on if `TheCore` is initialized or not, cannot be accessed with out `TheCore`. And simple usage of this Library from a 3rd Party app would simply be;**

**3rd Party App**

```
TheCore theCore = new TheCore.Builder()
                      .setSomeValues("Some Values")
                      .setMoreSomeValues("Some More Values")
                      .build();
theCore.someFancyTool.someStringMethod();
```

Note: Note that a the `ToolsInitializer.java` is still accessible and could be used the get private method without first calling `TheCore` but we can always set a checker inside `getSomeFancyTool()` method to `throw` error if some prerequisites are not satisfied.

I do not still know if this is a functional structural pattern to use or its just some hard thoughts of mine. And don't know if some pattern is already exist that I just could not see yet but this is the solution I end up with.

Comment: It is really not clear what the problem is that you were trying to solve.

Comment: Whats the part you did not catch? @scottb I just want a library that will have a main java class and it will include all subclasses inside as an object. Subclasses will be accessible only by main class no direct access.

Comment: So you want to create all your subclasses as nested private static classes (that each extend your top level class) within your top level class?